# The purview or scope of set theory qua set theory

Tags: set-theory

Even though set theory purports to offer a foundation for all of mathematical practice,
it would seem very odd to hear someone say, say, "I work in a narrow branch of set theory called partial differential equations."

My question:  how would a set theory expert in 2011 characterize the scope, or purview, or principal goals of his or her subject?  I have particular interest in aspects of the answer that might differ from what an expert might have said perhaps 20 years ago.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer, but I think that this text might be relevant to your question: http://shelah.logic.at/files/E16.pdf

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24854/what-are-the-issues-in-modern-set-theory/25563#25563 may prove to be a useful reading. 

Comment: with respect to the PDE joke, you might enjoy http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3733 